# If $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly and $f(z) =0$ only at $z_0$, then what can we say about $g(z_0)$, limiting function of $g_n(z) = f_n(z)^{1/n}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity, sequence-of-function

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a compact set and $ f_n: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a sequence of continuous functions uniformly converging to $f$.

Suppose $f(z_0) = 0$ and $f(z) \ne 0$ when $z \ne z_0$. Observe that $f$ is continuous but not necessarily holomorphic in any open subset of $A$.

We define a sequence of functions $g_n: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ given by $g_n(z) = |f_n(z)|^{1/n}$. With a limiting function being $g$.

What can we say - if anything - about the indeterminate $g(z_0)$.

My initial thoughts:

I thought $g(z) = 1 {z \in A, z \ne z_0}$ should be constant and therefore holomorphic and bounded in open punctured disk around $z_0$ and therefore we should be able to define $g(z_0) =1$ by Riemann’s Removable Singularity Theorem.

Then I wondered what would be the difference if we have $g_n(z) = f_n(z)^{1/\log(n)}$, $g_n(z) = f_n(z)^{1/\sqrt{n}}$, $g_n(z) = f_n(z)^{1/n^2}$, etc.

Is there a theorem that addresses this already?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Observe that $f$ is continuous"... Obviously it was given that the $f_n$ are continuous, though you didn't include that here. And $f_n^{1/n}$ is undefined in $\Bbb R$ if $f_n(z) < 0$ and $n$ is even, so I assume it was also given that $f_n(z) \ge 0$. Again, not mentioned. Is there anything else you left out?

Comment: And you use the term "holomorphic" when talking about $f$ and $g$. But these are real-valued functions, and "holomorphic" is a term defined for functions from $\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$. Real-valued functions are never holomorphic. You are correct that $$g(z) = \begin{cases}0, &z = z_0\\1,&z \ne z_0\end{cases}$$ The result will be the same for $g_n = f_n^{a_n}$ for any sequence $a_n$ converging to $0$ (except for $g(z_0)$ being undefined if $a_n$ has an infinite number of negative values).

Comment: Correct that to $g(z_0)$ being indeterminant. I was thinking of all the $f_n$ being $0$ there, but that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$ are sequences of real numbers with $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to 0$ as $n \to 0$. Further suppose that all $a_n > 0$ and $a > 0$. Then

$$\lim_n a_n^{b_n} = 1$$

Because $a > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for $n \ge N, |a_n - a| < a/2$. Let $$0 < m < \min\left\{\frac a2, \frac 2{3a}, a_n, \frac 1{a_n}\mid n < N\right\}$$ and $$M > \max\left\{\frac {3a}2, \frac 2a, a_n, \frac 1{a_n}\mid n < N\right\}$$

Then we have that $m < a_n < M$ and also $m < 1/a_n < M$ for all $n$. Therefore $$m^{|b_n|} < a_n^{b_n} < M^{|b_n|}$$

But because $b_n \to 0$, so does $|b_n|$ and therefore by continuity of the exponential function, $$\lim_n m^{|b_n|} = \lim_n M^{|b_n|} = 1$$

By the squeeze theorem, $a_n^{b_n} \to 1$ also.

The condition $a_n > 0$ can be dropped, provided $b_n \ge 0$ or one doesn't mind a finite number of undefined values in the sequence $a_n^{b_n}$ (finite because $a > 0$ means that eventually $a_n > 0$). However, the condition $a > 0$ is required.

So your conditions about $f_n$ converging uniformly and compactness of the domain - or even the domain being in $\Bbb C$ do not matter. By simple pointwise convergence, if $g_n = f_n^{b_n}$, then $g(z) = 1$ for all $z$ with $f(z) > 0$.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I’ve corrected the question based after reading your comments. I will need some time to read through the answer and see if I can think of any counter examples. I’ll accept the answer after i think it through.

Comment: With the corrections to the question, do you think $g(z_0)$ can be assigned value 1? Or to be more accurate, can we define $G$ such that $G(z) = g(z)$ when $z\ne z_0$ and $G(z_0) = 1$?

Comment: The main purpose of the exercise is to find conditions needed to get to a reasonable value of $g(z_0)$. Or rather figuring out what values it will take under various circumstances.

Comment: Your changes introduces a problem: $z \mapsto z^{b_n}$ is not single-valued in $\Bbb C$, so you have to choose a branch to use before you can discuss $f_n^{b_n}$. However, unless you are cutting through $1$, It will still be the case that unless $f(z) = 0$ the limit will still be $1$. My answer for real-valued sequences still shows that the norm of $g$ is $1$. And the argument of $f_n^{b_n}$ will decrease to $0$ as $b_n \to 0$. So, yes, you can define $G$ to be $1$ everywhere and have it agree with $g$ except possibly at $z = z_0$ where the limit depends on the exact behavior of the $f_n$.

Comment: If we take the primary branch defined as positive real number to fix the multi-value issue and add a uniform continuity requirement for $g(z)$ (eg by verifying the derivative with respect to $z$ is bounded, actually it would probably have to be 0) will that prove beyond doubt that $g(z_0)$ can be assigned value 0?

Comment: You define $z^w = e^{w\log z}$. The multivalue issue is because $e^z$ is a periodic function with period $2\pi i$. So for any integer $k, e^{v + k2\pi i} = e^v$. Therefore the value of its inverse function $\log z$ is only defined unto a multiple of $2\pi i$. A branch of the function is a strip $\Bbb R + i(a, a+2\pi]$ (or $\Bbb R + i[a,a+2\pi)$) in the complex plane where you choose the values of $\log z$ to reside. The "principle branch" is $i(-\pi,\pi]$, which puts the branch cut along the negative real axis. However, other branches are regularly used when it is advantageous to do so.

Comment: But I was mistaken about the branch chosen being an issue. Regardless of which one is chosen, the argument will eventually converge to $0$, and so the number must converge to $1$. But you cannot put conditions on $g(z)$ and still demand it be the limit of $f_n^{b_n}$. If you want $g(z_0) = 1$, then you have to put limits on on the givens, not the derived values. For example, you could require that $$\frac {f_n(z_0)}{b_n}$$ be bounded away from $0$. This would be enough to guarantee $f_n(z_0)^{b_n} \to 1$.

Comment: I took it to mean n-th root has n possible values, and function should be single valued. We often consider one “primary root” when considering $\sqrt{x}$ or $\sqrt{z}$, so that’s what I meant when I said let’s select positive real value as a “main branch”. Anyways, any thoughts about bounded derivative as a condition that would help nail down $g(z_0)$ I suspect the derivative will depend on the rate of exponent function and will help decide which exponent results in positive or negative pole singularity and which results in removable singularity.

Comment: About putting conditions on $g(z)$ I meant this: Of the several options for exponent functions $1/n^2, 1/n, 1/n^{\alpha}, 1/\log(n), 1/\log \log n, ...$ each resulting in isolated singularity and probably only one of them is removable singularity and rest are poles....

Comment: .....The removable singularity will depend on rate at which $f(z)$ goes to zero. One way to figure out which exponent results in removable singularity is to check - if possible- the derivative of $g(z)$ resulting from each option of exponent. When the derivative is bounded, $g(z)$ is uniformly continuous and will have value $1$. Any possible way of finding uniform continuity will work.

Comment: They are all removable singularities. $g(z) = 1$ everywhere but at $z_0$. That is not the behavior of a pole. The derivative of $g$ is *always zero*., except at $z_0$. If it happens that $f_n(z_0)^{b_n} \to 1$, then $g'(z_0) = 0$ as well, but otherwise $g$ does not have a derivative at $0$. This "singularity" is always removable by re-defining $g(z_0) = 1$, since it is $1$ everywhere else. You can always find a $b_n$ that will make it converge to $1$ - in particular, $b_n = f_n(z_0)$ will do it: $x^x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. You are making far too much of this.

Comment: So it is! I mean I was worried about various combinations like $x^{x^2}, x^{2x}, x^{\sqrt{x}}$ etc. as $x\rightarrow 0$, and $ (1-y)^{1-\log(ey)}$, etc. as $y\rightarrow 1$ and all kinds of combinations. They all seem to work out. Thank you!